# Which organism has the smallest genome length?

Tags: dna, genomes

Which animal/plant/anything has smallest length genome?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Since you said plant/animal/anything, I offer the smallest genomes in various categories...

(Kb means Kilobases, Mb means Megabases. 1 Kb = 1000 base pairs, 1Mb = 1000Kb)

- Smallest plant genome: *Genlisea margaretae* at 63Mb ([Greilhuber et al., 2006](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1055/s-2006-924101/abstract;jsessionid=9DD396FA89FD33C27678C0FE3C7A0895.d01t04))
- Smallest animal genome: *Pratylenchus coffeae* (nematode worm) at 20Mb ([Animal Genome Size DB](https://www.genomesize.com/statistics.php?stats=entire))
- Smallest vertebrate genome: *Tetraodon nigroviridis* (pufferfish) at 385Mb ([Jailon et al., 2004](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15496914/))
- Smallest eukaryote: *Encephalitozoon cuniculi* (microsporidian) at 2.9Mb ([Vivarès & Méténier, 2004](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4020-7846-0_12))
- Smallest free-living bacterial genome: *Nanoarchaeum eqitans* at 491Kb ([Waters et al., 2003](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/14566062/))
- Smallest bacterial genome: *Carsonella ruddii* (endosymbiont) at 160Kb ([Nakabachi et al., 2006](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.1134196))
- Smallest genome of anything: *Circovirus* at 1.8Kb (only 2 proteins!!) ([Chen et al., 2003](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12745370/))

**Refs...**

- [Chen, C.-L., Chang, P.-C., Lee, M.-S., Shien, J.-H., Ou, S.-J. & Shieh, H.K. (2003) Nucleotide sequences of goose circovirus isolated in Taiwan. Avian Pathology: Journal of the W.V.P.A. 32 (2), 165–171.](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12745370/)
- [Greilhuber, J., Borsch, T., Müller, K., Worberg, A., Porembski, S. & Barthlott, W. (2006) Smallest Angiosperm Genomes Found in Lentibulariaceae, with Chromosomes of Bacterial Size. Plant Biology. 8 (6), 770–777.](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1055/s-2006-924101/abstract;jsessionid=9DD396FA89FD33C27678C0FE3C7A0895.d01t04)
- [Jaillon, O., Aury, J.-M., Brunet, F., Petit, J.-L., Stange-Thomann, N., Mauceli, E., Bouneau, L., Fischer, C., Ozouf-Costaz, C., Bernot, A., Nicaud, S., Jaffe, D., Fisher, S., Lutfalla, G., et al. (2004) Genome duplication in the teleost fish Tetraodon nigroviridis reveals the early vertebrate proto-karyotype. Nature. 431 (7011), 946–957.](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1055/s-2006-924101/abstract;jsessionid=9DD396FA89FD33C27678C0FE3C7A0895.d01t04)
- [Nakabachi, A., Yamashita, A., Toh, H., Ishikawa, H., Dunbar, H.E., Moran, N.A. & Hattori, M. (2006) The 160-Kilobase Genome of the Bacterial Endosymbiont Carsonella. Science. 314 (5797), 267–267.](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.1134196)
- [Vivarès, C.P. & Méténier, G. (2004) Opportunistic Infections: Toxoplasma, Sarcocystis, and Microsporidia. In: World Class Parasites. Springer US. pp. 215–242.](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4020-7846-0_12)
- [Waters, E., Hohn, M.J., Ahel, I., Graham, D.E., Adams, M.D., Barnstead, M., Beeson, K.Y., Bibbs, L., Bolanos, R., Keller, M., Kretz, K., Lin, X., Mathur, E., Ni, J., et al. (2003) The genome of Nanoarchaeum equitans: insights into early archaeal evolution and derived parasitism. Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America. 100 (22), 12984–12988.](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/14566062/)

Comment: Well done! How did you find these?

Comment: The plant and bacterial ones I had floating around in my memory having read about them previously, so a bit of googling confirmed the names. The animal ones I got from the Animal Genome Size DB, and from Wikipedia. I guessed that viral genomes would be the smallest, so I also searched for the smallest viral genome. Then I went back to the literature (by searching Google Scholar for organism name + "genome size") to check all my facts and provide reliable references.

Comment: Nice answer Richard.

Comment: Smallest free-living bacterial genome: Nanoarchaeum eqitans at 491Kb (Waters et al., 2003)
I downloaded this paper it says that this is archaea and its obligate symbiont not a free living bacteria. Please read carefully and then upload it.

Comment: "Smallest genome of anything" is wrong. There are virus-like elements like viroids with as little as ~200 bp 'genomes'. Some viroids have as little as one RNA enzyme, others have not even this.

Answer (score 10):

I want to say *Mycoplasma genitalium* with a genome size of 582,970 bp. Turns out the answer is *Nanoarchaeum eqitans* with a genome of 490,885 bp.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanoarchaeum

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14566062

Comment: That's the smallest genome of a free-living organism. And until 2003 you would have been right about Mycoplasma, which were previously the smallest known in that category.

Answer (score 2):

Both *Mycoplasma genitalium* and *Nanoarchaeum equitans* are obligate parasites / endosymbionts. This means that they depend heavily on their host to support their vital functions and they have lost many of their own genes.

A really free-living organism with an extremely small genome (~1309 kbp, 1354 genes) is the heterotrophic marine alpha-proteobacterium *Pelagibacter ubique* [1].

See a larger analysis here: https://alamot.github.io/smallest_genome/

[1]: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16109880 Giovannoni SJ, Tripp HJ, Givan S, Podar M, Vergin KL, et al. (2005). «Genome streamlining in a cosmopolitan oceanic bacterium». Science 309: 1242–1245.